# React router in TypeScript- both router and own props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

my component has some own props

```
class Props {
  wizard: WizardConfig;
}
```

and I want to access router history so I also pass router props

```
type PropsType = Props & RouteComponentProps<{}>;

class Wizard extends React.Component<PropsType> {}
```

The problem is that in component's usage

```
 <Wizard wizard={someWizar} />
```

I get errors that `RouteComponentProps` props are not passed so for example: 
   `Property 'match' is missing in type '{ wizard: WizardConfig; }'`

I tried to do:

```
export default withRouter(Wizard);
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: If you want the type to have one or more properties of Route... but not all of them, you could try declaring as a Partial - _Partial<RouteCom...>_

Answer (score 3):

**Fixed** by changing

```
export default withRouter(Wizard);
```

to

```
export default withRouter<PropsType>(Wizard);
```